# How to prove that certain integers and xy are solutions for a relation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:
Let A be the set of all integers of the form a^2 + b^2 + 4ab where a and b are integers.
Prove:

a. if x and y are in A, prove xy is in A.

b. Prove 121 is in A and 11 is not in A.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick proof of (b).

(b) $121 = 4^2 + 5^2 +4(4)(5),$ which is of the required form, so $121 \in A.$ Now, *if* $11$ were in $A,$ we could write $$11 = c^2+d^2+4cd$$ for some $c, d \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Then $$c^2 + 4cd + d^2 - 11 = 0$$ which is a quadratic in $c.$ The discriminant is $(4d)^2 - 4(d^2-11) = 12d^2 + 44,$ which must be a perfect square, so $3d^2+11$ must be a perfect square. But $3d^2+11$ is $2$ modulo $3,$ a contradiction. $\square$

Alternately, start right from the beginning: taking modulo $3$ on $11 = c^2+d^2 +4cd$ gives $c^2+d^2 +cd\equiv 2 \pmod{3}.$ But this is actually impossible for **all** choices of $c, d$ (try them out, there are only $6$ you need to care about because of symmetry).

Comment: Why can $c$ only be 1 or 9? $cd$ could be negative.

Comment: Good point, I missed that. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$a^2+4ab+b^2=(a+2b)^2-3b^2$$

Now set $a+2b=c$ and use [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity) to find  $$(c^2+nb^2)(x^2+ny^2)=(cx\pm nby)^2+n(cy\mp bx)^2$$

In our case $n=-3$